# Celery Beat stops running tasks without any errors

Tags: django, kubernetes, celery, celerybeat

Celery beat is spinning in a container in the Kubernetes (1 replica).
Celery beat works for a few days, then it stops running scheduled tasks, and there are no errors in the logs, the logs look like this:

```
2023-04-08 13:56:57 
[2023-04-08 04:56:57,544: DEBUG/MainProcess] Current schedule:
2023-04-08 13:56:57 
[2023-04-08 04:56:57,532: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
2023-04-08 13:56:57 
[2023-04-08 04:56:57,532: DEBUG/MainProcess] Setting default socket timeout to 30
2023-04-08 13:56:52 
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
2023-04-08 13:56:52 
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%DEBUG
2023-04-08 13:56:52 
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
2023-04-08 13:56:52 
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
2023-04-08 13:56:52 
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
2023-04-08 13:56:52 
    . broker -> redis://192.168.68.4:6379/3
2023-04-08 13:56:52 
Configuration ->
2023-04-08 13:56:52 
LocalTime -> 2023-04-07 07:38:01
2023-04-08 13:56:52 
__    -    ... __   -        _
2023-04-08 13:56:52 
celery beat v4.3.0 (rhubarb) is starting.
```

When celery beat stops running tasks:

```
[2023-04-08 00:05:00,081: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Synchronizing schedule...
[2023-04-08 00:05:00,087: DEBUG/MainProcess] 2. <crontab: 0 0 * * * (m/h/d/dM/MY)> 86099.912976 > 0
[2023-04-08 00:05:00,087: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 minutes.
[2023-04-08 00:10:00,187: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Synchronizing schedule...
[2023-04-08 00:10:00,190: DEBUG/MainProcess] 2. <crontab: 0 0 * * * (m/h/d/dM/MY)> 85799.809269 > 0
[2023-04-08 00:10:00,191: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 minutes.
[2023-04-08 00:15:00,290: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Synchronizing schedule...
[2023-04-08 00:15:00,293: DEBUG/MainProcess] 2. <crontab: 0 0 * * * (m/h/d/dM/MY)> 85499.7061 > 0
...etc...
```

What could be the reason?

I turned on DEBUG level logs, but they didn't show anything, just as if there are no new tasks, although there are configured periodic tasks.